# Laravel 5.7 Display image from public storage in blade

Tags: laravel

I have had a really hard time getting an image to show in a laravel blade from my public storage.  I'm stuck using this way due to Envoyer has a sim link to the storage and would over write my images directory on each deployment.

I have checked my link path

```
php artisan storage:link
The "public/storage" directory already exists.
```

I have setup a path in my filesystem.php

```
   'avitar' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root' => storage_path('app/public/images/users/'),
       'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
       'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

My path to my users is

```
storage->app->public->images->user->default.png
```

for the image links I have tried the following with no luck

```
src="{{ Storage::disk('avitar')->url('default.png') }}"
src="{{ asset('storage/images/users/default.png') }}"
src="{{ url('storage/images/users/default.png') }}"
src="{{ Storage::disk('avitar')->url('app/public/images/users/default.png') }}"
src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url('images/users/default.png') }}"
src="{{ Storage::disk('avitar')->url('default.png') }}"
```

Any Thoughts or help would be great
Thanks

Comment: Think your `public/storage` isnt a symlink but a folder. Please confirm with `cd public && ls -la` and see if it points somwhere else, if not, see if `storage` has files in it with `ls -la storage`. If it have no files, delete folder and re-run storage link: `rm -rf storage && cd ../ && php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's a typo or not but your "user" folder is singular in the provided path `storage->app->public->images->user->default.png` and you use `users` as plural il your config file `app/public/images/users/default.png`

Comment: Thanks, yes I did see that after.  It was a broken simlink from my public storage.  Both are filled with files and didn't notice to files had not been linking

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.  My storage simlink had broken.

Comment: maybe just delete this question altogether since it doesn't bing any value to the website?

Comment: You can't delete the question altogether, site will not let you